# Text link to change the bootstrap tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap tabs and some added jquery to show the tab based on the url. What I want to achieve is to have the same behaviour with a simple text link but I don't know what I am missing.

So, while in the first-tab, to click on below:

```
<a class="xam" href="#second-tab">link to other page tab</a>
```

and navigate to the second-tab.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li><a href="#first-tab" data-toggle="tab">first<i class="fa"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#second-tab" data-toggle="tab">second<i class="fa"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

here is the jquery

```
var url = document.location.toString();
if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + url.split('#')[1] + '"]').tab('show');
} 

// Change hash for page-reload
$('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
})
```

Comment: try this - `$('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + url.split("#")[1] + '"]').tab('show');` I have used `url.split("#")` instead of `url.split('#')` or just save `url.split('#')[1]` in some `var` and use it. The quotes (',") might create issue.

Comment: @Developer107 i don't think you understood the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this?

```
$('.xam').on('click', function(){
  var tab = $(this).attr("href");
  $('a[href="'+tab+'"]').tab('show')
  $(tab).tab('show')
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me too with bootstrap tabs.